# Taking a cutting from cherry Tree

Tags: fruit-trees, propagation, cuttings, rooting-hormone

I'm travelling around various family members all over the UK for the next week.

The family members I'm with at the moment have a really gorgeous cherry tree that I would really like a cutting from, but won't get it home to do the actual rooting (hormone and potting) for another 5 days.

How long after taking the cutting off of the tree will it remain possible to successfully root it?

Is there anything I can do to maximise my chances of getting it home healthy? I would obviously take a few cuttings to increase my chances, but wondered if it is even worth it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot answer the detailed questions, but put the cuttings in a plastic zip-top bag with a few bits of damp paper/cardboard/sphagnum moss/etc. - seal it tightly, but leave as much air inside as is practical if they are leafed.

It isn't essential, but the longer you can keep them refrigerated until you can strike them, the better. Also, if you have 3% hydrogen peroxide handy, mix it with water at the rate of 2 tablespoons per quart. Drench your cuttings and shake them off before bagging them. This should nix possible bacterial/fungal issues for the time.

Good luck (is always needed).

Answer (score 5):

Having tried this (unsuccessfully) with "spring cuttings" (friends were moving and leaving their house with cherry tree, so it was then or never) my research into it suggested taking cuttings in the fall and letting them develop roots over the winter as being much more likely to succeed. As such, while you certainly could try to pack in damp newspaper and keep cool now, if your family will still be there in the fall, that would be a better time to take cuttings.